# Encrypted in Java using RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding unable to decrypt in .Net

Tags: c#, java, cryptography, rsa, x509

I have a string that's encrypted using some crypto classes in Java (RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding) and a public key we exchanged in advance.

I want to decrypt that string using our private key and this is the code I have.

```
 X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("c:\\test.pfx", "test");
        string s =               "very long encrypted data";

        RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKeyProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

        string decryptedTest = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(privateKeyProvider.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(s), true));
```

I get an exception with error message.

"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding"

What is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In which line do you get the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `Decrypt` with the second parameter set to `false`. 
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.decrypt.aspx)

> ...false to use PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.

Comment: I figured it out but, I will give you the credit. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code.

```
 X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("c:\\test.pfx", "test");
    string s =               "very long encrypted data";

    RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKeyProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

    string decryptedTest = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(privateKeyProvider.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(s), true));
```